# Zxing camera becomes slow when calling StartScanning second time in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, tabs, fragment, zxing

Please see the screenshot attached.
The first time swipe from tab1 to Scan tab, it works perfectly. However, if I swipe to another tab then swipe back to Scan tab again. It takes about 8 seconds for the ScanFragment to come back. 
I'm using Xamarin for Android.
I tried to use PauseAnalysis when swipe to a tab other than Scan tab that is when it becomes slow. 
I tried to use StopScanning when swipe away from Scan tab, but the problem is when swipe back to Scan tab, the camera does not really focus.

Any help will be really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In my app I have the Zxing scanner as a fragment, I call scanFragment.StopScanning(); when going out, and  scanFragment.scan(); when comming back.

Comment: Do you also use tabs in your app? I think the problem comes when the tab is recreated.

Comment: No, I have the camera as a fragment using half on the screen, and I have menus on both sides, I stop the scan every time on of the menus is showed and launch it again every time the menu is hidded. Can you show some code of the tab creation to see if I can try it by myself?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Would you mind to quickly drop me an email to bwwilliam@gmail.com. I will send my whole project to you if that is ok.

Comment: Hi Mulflar, I have sent you the source code hope you received it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I recived, let me have free time to check it, this week I will tell you about